# HTML5 Geolocation + javascript help needed

Tags: geolocation

I want to make use of html5 geolocation and make use of the latitude and longitude for php.
If the user gives permission to give his location, the function needs to be called.
I want to refesh the page partly by taking information of this page:

example.php?latitude=xxxx&longitude=xxx

I already know how to refresh a div with a page with this:
$('#test_content').load('example.php);

but how do I get it work this way

```
<script>
getLocation();
$('#test_content').load('example.php?latitude=' + position.coords.latitude);
</script>
```

I am very bad in javascript and thats my big problem.

I know I am making big mistakes but I don't know what..
This is the code I use for geolocation:

```
// JavaScript Document
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code) 
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML="User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML="Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML="The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML="An unknown error occurred."
      break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your script you'll need to cut out these line of the first script -    `$('#test_content').load('example.php?latitude=' + position.coords.latitude);`

and insert int in the  `showPosition` function instead all the other stuff you've got there between the function brackets.